# Amend author of Git commit and leave original commit date

Tags: git

Is there a way to amend the author of Git commit and leave original commit date?

For example I changed a commit author on a commit that was pushed on Tuesday, however when I successfully changed the author, the commit date has also been changed to today, which is Wednesday. How do I change the author and keep the original date of Tuesday?

```
exec git commit --amend --author="John <john@mail.com>" -C HEAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can set the `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` which is used for commit timestamp. By default it would be the current time. We can override it based on the commit timestamp by doing something like this:

`exec GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(git show -s --format=%ci HEAD)" git commit --amend --author="John <john@mail.com>" -C HEAD`

We can also update the authorDate by using `git commit --amend --date` based on commits timestamp.

`exec git commit --amend --author="John <john@mail.com>" --date="$(git show -s --format=%ci HEAD)" -C HEAD`